# Is there anyway to populate distinct values using mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to populate my user property which is an array of duplicate id's and a reference to the User Schema.

```
schema={
  
  // Array of duplicate userId
  user: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID,
        ref:'Users'
    }]  

}
```

Can I populate only distinct id's using mongoose here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can by following method.

```
db.collection_name.ensureIndex( { user : 1 }, { unique:true, sparse:true } );
```